# install tomcat and java and run jsp in the browser

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

For quite a while I have worked in the LAMP stack. But now I need to work on a project in java ,jsp and servlets(Tomcat Server) I have never worked in java ,jsp before. So I need some help in setting up the stuff in my laptop so that i can execute a java and jsp script in my browser. I know there are numerous links in the web that provide tutorials. But could someone point me to good one where it shows all the steps:for eg:

Installing Tomcat

Installing java

compiling,build,test java,jsp,servlets in the browser

Or anything else that would help me get started and learn the right way to develop web applications

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think [this tutorial from Lars Vogel](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseWTP/article.html) is a comprehensive one and is quite up-to-date.

The only point not covered is "installing java", that should be your first step. This [article](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com.es/2011/12/jre-jvm-jdk-jit-in-java-programming.html) can help you in getting used to JDK, JRE, JVM, etc.